# Unity Array and Instatiation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im new in unity and I have  a problem regarding arrays. [image: Here is the editor snapshot]

I want to be able to set the Elements of the arrays via script. 
Here straight is a "public gridElementScript[] straight;"

Comment: and what is the problem on `Straight[0] = ...` or `Straight[1] = ...` or whatever you want to do with the objects?

Comment: I am instantiating an image prefab gridElementPrefab. I want to be able to assign specific gridElementPrefab to the straight array. Like they immediate neighboring grid element. The gridElementPrefab has the gridElementScript attached to it.

Comment: we still don't understand what exactly is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're asking how to access `Straight` from another instance. If so, you need to cast your instantiated prefab to a `GameObject` and call `GetComponent<MyComponent>()` on it. Something like I've written below should work for you.

```
GameObject object = (GameObject)Object.Instantiate(myPrefab)
GridElementScript script = object.GetComponent<GridElementScript>();
script.Straight[0] = neighbor
```

Comment: ...and there should be a canonical dupe target around somewhere